# Move all of root into a subfolder

Tags: git

In my git repo, the application is located in the root folder, like

```
.gitignore
pom.xml
data/
src/
README.md
...
```

due to a redesign of the application (one part is to introduce a parent pom), it i want to move everything into a subfolder, e.g. called system, and then create a second folder (e.g. called api):

```
system/
    .gitignore
    pom.xml
    data/
    src/
    README.md
    ...
api/
    src
    ...
...
```

What is the best way to move everything to `system`? Is git mv for each file/directory in the root directory enough?

Comment: You could also just mv the files to system with the standard bash command (just 'mv' not 'git mv') and then commit the changes to your repository, no?

Comment: Please define "best".

Comment: "best": keeping changes / commit messages without destroying the repo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by using `git ls-files` to get all the files tracked by git, and then loop over them, moving each one to the new `system/` directory:

```
git ls-files | for f in $(cat -); do git mv $f system; done
```

Comment: doesn't this just flatten the structure?  i don't see how this can work?

Comment: Does at least not work on Windows 7 with git-bash. It's flattening all files without subdirectories into destination directory. **NOT A SOLUTION**

Answer (score 1):

Simply move everything (except for the `.git` directory) into the new folder, run `git add --all`, and commit.

Comment: On Windows, moving files/folders to a subfolder and then doing git add --all will create "delete/add-actions" in GIT (as opposed to "rename-actions") which will destroy the history. It seems like one must do git mv to prevent loss of history on file level, at least on Windows.

Comment: @EmilG, have you tried both approaches and seen a difference? Because git doesn't actually store "actions"; it just stores snapshots of the directory, and determines the "actions" from the diff. `git mv` is basically a shortcut for manually moving a file/dir and doing `git add --all`

Comment: Yes, you're probably right, looking closer at both approaches, I think they produce the same result like you said. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution described in this gist worked for me (and it keeps the subdirectory structure of the moved folders): https://gist.github.com/ajaegers/2a8d8cbf51e49bcb17d5

The relevant command is: `for file in $(ls | grep -v 'system'); do git mv $file system; done;`

Answer (score 0):

To improve on a Markus and tlehman's anser to make it work with sub directoris I made this
Where you move everythign to a folder called "subdir"

```sh
git ls-files | \
        for f in $(cat -); do
                mkdir -p $(dirname "subdir/$f")
                git mv "$f" "subdir/$f"
        done
```

Then run

```sh
git clean -fd
```

to remove the old directory entries.

Hint: in Zsh you can span multiple lines with alt + enter. Bash doesn't seem to have an equivalent. (I guess you can end the line with `;\` and you can add more commands)